# UIPickerView with UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm new to swift and I'm trying to add a picture from the gallery/camera to an image view and also pass it backward and store it in the array. Below is what I have so far I can click the button and show me an action sheet that takes me to the gallery and the camera just don't know how to assign it to my imageView and pass the image info back.

```
    @IBAction func addPhoto(_ sender: Any) {

         showSimpleActionSheet(controller: self)
        
    }


func showSimpleActionSheet(controller: UIViewController) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose an image", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
            self.getImage(fromSourceType: .camera)
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
            self.getImage(fromSourceType: .photoLibrary)
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (_) in
           
        }))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
            
        })
    }

extension NewViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func getImage(fromSourceType sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType){
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(sourceType){
            let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePickerController.delegate = self
            imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType
            
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
         } else {
            print("Source type isn't available")
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create an image picker controller, you have to set a delegate. That delegate must conform to the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol.

The image picker controller will invoke it’s delegate’s methods to notify it when the user picks an image/movie. That’s where you would accept the user-selected image and install it into your image view (or whatever it is you want to do with the image).

The delegate method that tells you what media the user selected is `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)`.

Show us your implementation of that method.

Comment: OK so I did this, 
   

 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
            return
        }
        imageView.image = image
    }

Comment: Edit your question to include your delegate method. Also add a breakpoint or print statement to your delegate method to make sure it is called, and log the value returned. BTW, you should probably get the image before dismissing the picker. (switch the order of those 2 lines.)